# An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of dnx hosting your application. Invalid query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have updated VS 2015 with SP1, and this is generating some problem running applications on ASP.NET 5 with error shown above.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166403/an-error-occurred-attempting-to-determine-the-process-id-of-the-dnx-process-host

Comment: No, it doesn't work to me. I did what it was suggested. Probably the problem is with new update of APS.NET 5