# Debug error in ASP.NET 5 project in VS2015 Community Edition that was developed in VS2015 Enterprise Ed

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I copied an ASP.NET 5 MVC6 project from VS2015 Ent. Ed to VS2015 Community Ed. The project successfully compiles but when I run it (using F5) I get the following error: `An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of the DNX process hosting your application`
When I run it using ctrl+F5, I get the following error: `HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error: The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.`

**UPDATE**
I'm using this [official ASP.NET tutorial](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/) that is using IISExpress and localDb. The app was developed on VS2015 Ent Ed on Windows 7 and then I opened the app on Windows 8.1 with VS2015 Community Edition. It seems the localDb is missing. `Does the localDb not get copied when you copy the entire app from one machine to another?`

Comment: Have you tried searching for those errors?

Comment: Did you try deleting the project.lock.json file as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166403/an-error-occurred-attempting-to-determine-the-process-id-of-the-dnx-process-host/34357929#34357929)?

Comment: Have you tried simply to reload visual studio? It helped me with the same error.  Also check all your devenv processes and drop them.  Finally check your dnx version

Comment: @dotctor I tried searching online but it seems my case is slightly different. I've added an `Update` to my post.

Comment: @DanielGrim I tried your suggestion. Now I'm getting the following error: `Cannot open database "aspnet5-MvcMovie-....." requested by the login. The login failed.` It seems the localDb is missing. I've added an `Update` section to my post

Comment: Is it possible that this is a permissions issue (web user can't access database)? I get your original error message (..."determine the process id"...) when I uncheck the "Enable Anonymous Authentication" checkbox at the bottom of the "Debug" tab in VS project properties.